# Is quadrature still considered part of numerical analysis?

Tags: soft-question, na.numerical-analysis, quadrature

This question may admittedly sound strange, but having received several desk-rejects (all of them being based on being "out of scope" for the journal in question) from numerical analysis journals for a paper about quadrature rules, with the most recent one explicitly recommending submission to an approximation theory journal instead (even though the paper is at best very tenuously related to approximation), I wonder whether quadrature (in spite of being part of the undergraduate syllabus of numerical mathematics at any institution I'm aware of) is no longer seen as part of numerical mathematics at the research level. Any numerical analysts willing to add their 2¢?

Comment: On a given subject, it is generally useful to see where recent papers have been published, where there are editors closest to the subject. It can help in choosing the right place to submit.

Comment: The thing is that there aren't any recent papers that take a similar approach to quadrature rules.

Comment: Editors use sometimes not very relevant arguments for rejecting a paper. I had an experience with a paper on combinatorial aspects of $SL_2$ over finite fields: It was rejected by combinatorists arguing that it was group-theory and group-theorists claiming that it was combinatorics.

Comment: @RolandBacher That sounds interesting. Link?

Comment: @HAHelfgott : https://arxiv.org/pdf/1506.01604.pdf (published in J. Comb. Math. Comb. Comput. 109, 137-155 (2019)., I submitted it first to the Journals of the LMS where it got pingponged between various editors).

Comment: Almost any journal publishing "papers in all areas of mathematics" does not do so. To avoid stoking the flames, I will not post links, but easy search will find a number of articles and blogs documenting particular grievances. Same holds for the journals whose scope is "all of [subject area]". Every journal is the sum of its editorial board, and so possesses the usual human shortcomings (ignorance, laziness, etc).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Math journals that have recently published papers on "quadrature" include

- [Applied Numerical Mathematics](https://www.sciencedirect.com/journal/applied-numerical-mathematics)
- [IMA Journal of Numerical
  Analysis](https://academic.oup.com/imajna)
- [Journal of Approximation Theory](https://www.sciencedirect.com/journal/journal-of-approximation-theory)
- [Journal of Computational and Applied Mathematics](https://www.sciencedirect.com/journal/journal-of-computational-and-applied-mathematics)

Answer (score 6):

This question cannot be answered without knowing more about your preprint and the specific journal. As a few rules of thumb:

- Much of "numerical mathematics" has been numerical mathematics for ordinary and partial differential equations. That's how university curricula are set up in many countries. My impressions is that classical topics such as quadrature rules might be considered sufficiently explored.
- Topics related to data science have gained prominence in recent years, and  Monte-Carlo integration is of interest there.

I can roughly imagine why a journal with focus in numerical ODE/PDE/data analysis would refer a paper on quadrature rule to "approximation theory" or something similar: personally, I would not expect any earthshaking breakthroughs on quadrature rules, but rather some incremental improvements of constants.

Again, not much more can be said without knowing your work and specific journal. Just try to flesh out why your work is matters (practically or theoretically) and try out a different journal.